# How to convert objects to Array of objects

Tags: javascript

**My data**

```
var data={
    key:value,
    key:value,
    key:value
};
```

**Expected output**

```
var data=[
    {key:value},
    {key:value},
    {key:value}
];
```

Comment: i doubt that this is your data, if you declare it like this, your data is actually `var data = { key: value }`, so please give us a verifiable code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple for in loop is a way to handle this :

```js
var data = {
    key:  'value',
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
};
var arr = []; 
for(var k in data){
    var o = {}; 
    o[k]=data[k]; 
    arr.push(o)
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use several ES6 shorthands to produce the desired output in one expression:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => ({[key]: data[key]}))
```

The following code snippet demonstrates this:

```js
const data = {
  key0:'value0',
  key1:'value1',
  key2:'value2'
};

const output = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({[key]: data[key]}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

```js
var data = {
  key: 'value',
  key1: 'value',
  key2: 'value'
};

console.log(
  // get all object property names(keys)
  Object.keys(data)
  // iterate over the keys array
  .map(function(k) {
    // generate the obect and return
    var o = {};
    o[k] = data[k];
    return o;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to have the `keys`:

```
Object.keys(data)
console.log(Object.keys(data)[0]) // will print first key
```

Or you can use `Object.values` to get the values:

```
Object.values(data)
console.log(Object.values(data)[0]) // will print first key value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:-

```
function json2array(json){
var output = [];
var keys = Object.keys(json);
keys.forEach(function(key){
    output.push(json[key]);
});
return output;}
```